# Can update nginx all vhost at once for common changes?

Tags: nginx

Now my Apach + Nginx VPS has 6 sites. It uses Nginx admin plugin. All of these sites are WordPress and use standard installation. I want to know are there any simple method to update all the virtual hosts nginx configuration file at once without editing each vhost nginx configuration file (for common changes). For an instance if I need add W3total rewrite configuration to all of these sites, update vhost configuration file at once?

Answer (score 3):

Change your Nginx config files so that they all have [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive pointing to some common config file. Then you can make your changes in that one place and all your vhosts will automatically include it.

Comment: @chris if this solution worked for you, tag this as accepted answer, otherwise update your question indicating why include can't be used.